# Dropping columns used as condition when highlighting the column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have highlighted pandas dataframe using conditional statement (highlight one column as yellow if other column value is `True`). Before exporting to Excel I want to remove the conditional column I used. But I got error message.

Here is what I have done:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
def highlight_col(val):
    data = pd.DataFrame('', index=val.index, columns=val.columns)
    if val['Email Updated'].any():
        data.loc[val['Email Updated'], 'Email'] = f"background-color: yellow"
    return data

styled_df = df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
styled_df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', index = False)
```

After export I want to drop `Email Updated` column and keep `email` column.

So far I have tried

```
data.drop('Email Updated', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

and

```
styled_df.drop('Email Updated', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

But without success.

Thank you!

Comment: `styled_df = df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)` is an `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` object, not a dataframe, as such, dataframe methods don't work on it.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney is there a way to achieve what I was looking for using dataframe methods then?

Comment: `styled_df = styled_df.hide(['updated'], axis='columns')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one of the options :

```
import numpy as np

#is email updated ?
m = df["Email Updated"]

styled_df = (df.drop(columns="Email Updated").style.apply(
             lambda _: np.where(m, f"background-color: yellow", ""), subset="Email"))

#another variant
#styled_df = (df[["Email"]].style.apply( #feel free to add more columns
#             lambda _: np.where(m, f"background-color: yellow", ""), subset="Email"))

styled_df.to_excel("filename.xlsx", index=False)
```

Or, following your approach (*for pandas >= 1.4.0*), you can chain it with [`hide`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide.html) :

```
styled_df = (df.style.apply(highlight_col, axis=None)
                     .hide(subset=["Email Updated"], axis=1))
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: ```hide``` option won't work for me for some reason. I am using pandas version 2.0.1. In my excel sheet still I can see ```Email Updated``` column. Strange

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention it! This is the normal behaviour because only the `apply_*` methods add styles that can be exported to an Excel spreadsheet ([*read here*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Methods-to-Add-Styles)). So, the first approach is your only option (*for now*).

Comment: The first option drops ```Email Updated``` column before applying the style. The style depends on ```True``` value of ```Email Updated```. This is causing ```KeyError: "['Email updated'] not found in axis" ```

Comment: No, the 1st solution with `drop` works without any problem (*because the mask `m` is created before the drop*). You're using another code for sure that triggers the `KeyError`. Anyways, I added another variant that should also work for you ;)

Comment: Thank you so much your code is working. When I just apply to several columns (columns that have been highlighted based on TRUE or FALSE condition, it select the entire row (I have several other columns). But my existing code selects the corresponding value related to TRUE. Is is possible to modify your solution in such way? Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. You can use the `subset` parameter, see update ;)